# Merge tags: [cypher] and [cypher-query]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I think these two tags [cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypher) and [cypher-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypher-query) refer to the same thing:

[cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypher) description:

> Cypher is a graph query language for Neo4j and AgensGraph...

[cypher-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cypher-query) description:

> Cypher is Neo4j’s graph query language that allows users to store and
> retrieve data from the graph database

Also we do not have an "sql-query" tag for SQL so why for Cypher? as both of them are query languages.

Excuse me if anything is incorrect but this is my first meta question.

Comment: Just as an FYI, burninate is for removing tags, which is not what you're asking for here

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and synonymed them since

1. The descriptions are for the same thing
2. [cypher-query] has only 3 questions (one of which has both tags)

I'll leave off the merge for now in case anyone still objects, but I suspect there won't be any.